# Larger .maxstack when not storing a reference?

Tags: c#, intermediate-language

I am no IL master of any sort, I just use it sometimes to check what the compiler makes of the code that I write. One thing that I have been wondering about is why `.maxstack` gets the value it gets sometimes. Consider the following class:

```
public class Sample
{
    public void SomeMethod(){}
}
```

Then, I have a program like this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Sample sample = new Sample();
    sample.SomeMethod();      
}
```

The above code gives the following IL (Release compiled):

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       13 (0xd)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class ConsoleApplication1.Sample sample)
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication1.Sample::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  stloc.0
  IL_0006:  ldloc.0
  IL_0007:  callvirt   instance void ConsoleApplication1.Sample::SomeMethod()
  IL_000c:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Now, if I change the program code into this:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Sample().SomeMethod();  
}
```

...it results in the following IL code:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  newobj     instance void ConsoleApplication1.Sample::.ctor()
  IL_0005:  call       instance void ConsoleApplication1.Sample::SomeMethod()
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

The second IL code is shorter, which was expected. But what gets me a bit curious is why `.maxstack` i 8 in the second code sample, but 1 in the first? Why does the second code lead to the system reserving a larger stack for the operation?

Comment: Is this in debug or release mode? I wonder what the necessity of stdloc.0 and ldloc.0 is, other than making debugging easier.

Comment: @Cecil: it is release complied (as stated in the question, however buried in the text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binary representation of a method header has a "tiny format" and a "fat format". The tiny header takes fewer bytes and can be used as long as the following conditions are met:

- Max stack <= 8
- No exception handling
- No local variables
- Code size < 64 bytes

Your change allowed the compiler to use this form, and when a tiny header is encountered it is always assumed to use a max stack of 8.

[Reference is ECMA-335 §25.4.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm)

**On a side note** Of particular interest to me is the fact that in a release build (per your note in the OP) they produced different code, where the shortened form is both smaller and faster. What version of C# are you using? I would expect later versions to take advantage of this obvious optimization:

- The local variable could be removed without changing the semantics.
- When the local variable is not present, the compiler knows the concrete type of the value is exactly `Sample`, so even though `SomeMethod` is virtual it can call it directly with the `call` instruction.